# Stored procedure para seleccionar campos de distintas tablas con funcion COUNT - SQLServer 2014

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Necesito hacer un SP que me permite mostrar para un determinado hotel y en un rango de fechas, la cantidad de habitaciones libres y la cantidad de habitaciones ocupadas. Luego debo agruparlas por fecha y categoría.
Tengo las tablas: Hotel, Reservas, Categoria y Ocupacion.
Hasta ahora tengo solo las cantidades de habitaciones libres y ocupadas

```
select SUM(Cantidad_ocupantes) as 'Habitaciones ocupadas',
  (select COUNT(Cantidad_ocupantes) from Ocupacion where Cantidad_ocupantes=0) as 'Habitaciones Libres' 
from Ocupacion
```

Agradezco todas las ideas que me presenten.

[image: Relaciones de las tablas]

Comment: Hola.. vamos a necesitar ver las estructuras de las tablas y unos datos de ejemplo. Por lo que estas diciendo, el query no es nada sencillo, ya que por ejemplo supongo que la ocupacion sera la que esta por fechas. y no se que tenga que ver la categoria.

Comment: Bien, ahora adjunto una imagen con las tablas. La categoría se refiere a la categoría que tiene una habitación, hay 3 categorías distintas "Standard", "Standard de lujo" y "Suite"

Comment: Comparto la opinión de @gbianchi, comparte estructura y datos para poderte ayudar.

Comment: Procura siempre incluir en tus preguntas de BD, la definición de los campos y algunos datos de prueba, siempre como texto, para que otros puedan probar sus respuestas y ayudarte más rápido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obtuve algo parecido con la ayuda de @Rostan

```
declare @Fecha_Reserva_Desde date = '20170601'
declare @Fecha_Reserva_Hasta date = '20170603'

SELECT Ho.Descripcion as Hotel, O.Fecha, C.Decripcion, SUM(Cantidad_ocupantes) as 'Habitaciones ocupadas',
(select COUNT(Cantidad_ocupantes) from Ocupacion where Cantidad_ocupantes=0) as 'Habitaciones Libres' 
FROM OCUPACION AS O
INNER JOIN HABITACIONES AS H
    ON (O.Codigo_habitacion = H.Codigo_habitacion)
INNER JOIN HOTELES AS Ho
    ON (H.Codigo_hotel = Ho.Codigo_hotel)
INNER JOIN CATEGORIAS AS C
    ON (C.Codigo_categoria = H.Codigo_categoria)
WHERE O.Fecha BETWEEN @Fecha_Reserva_Desde and @Fecha_Reserva_Hasta 
GROUP BY Ho.Descripcion, O.Fecha, C.Decripcion
ORDER BY Ho.Descripcion;
```

Obtuve lo siguiente:  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna 'Habitaciones Libres' me debería dar "17400" donde no haya ocupación, y donde hay 1 ocupación me debería dar 17399.

Comment: Si esta es la solución a tu pregunta, recuerda marcarla como aceptada

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo a tu agrupación, este sería el script que te ayudaría a saber cuantas habitaciones está ocupadas, por Hotel, Fecha y Categoria:

```
SELECT Ho.Descripcion, O.Fecha, C.Descripcion, COUNT(*)
FROM OCUPACION AS O
INNER JOIN HABITACIONES AS H
    ON (O.Codigo_habitacion = H.Codigo_habitacion)
INNER JOIN HOTELES AS Ho
    ON (H.Codigo_hotel = Ho.Codigo_hotel)
INNER JOIN CATEGORIAS AS C
    ON (C.Codigo_categoria = H.Codigo_categoria)
WHERE O.Fecha BETWEEN 'FechaInicio' and 'FechaFinal'
GROUP BY Ho.Descripcion, O.Fecha, C.Descripcion;
```

Quiero hacer incapié en que tome como fecha la de la Tabla Ocupación. Espero mi respuesta haya sido de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: No es exactamente lo que estoy buscando, esta consulta me muestra la cantidad de habitaciones por fecha, por categoría y por hotel.   Lo que necesito es la cantidad total de habitaciones ocupadas y la cantidad de habitaciones libres en un rango de fechas por categoria.   Igualmente gracias por la respuest, voy a ver si me sirve para darle una vuelta más al query para ver si logro llegar al resultado buscado.